# How do I apply a type of any to an object returned by an observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple observable that is being used to retrieve the data from the url `https://api.github.com/users`, I want to be able to map this data so that I can only return the `login` property from each user contained in the array returned by the endpoint.

However when I try to call `data => data.login` on my map function, I get a compiler error saying that `Property 'login' does not exist on type {}`. I understand this is because the object being returned has no type.

Without creating an interface for the returned object, how can I apply a type of `any` to the object being exposed by the observable so that I can use `map` to transform it?

```js
var githubStream = this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users');

githubStream.subscribe(out => {
    pipe(map(data => data.login))
});
```

Comment: Something like this `githubStream.subscribe((out: any) => {
      pipe(map(data => data.login))
    });`

Comment: For that specific observable, as it supports generic types, `this.http.get<any>(...)`? But it would be better to be more specific - write an interface that represents the actual returned value. See https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response.

Comment: @GopeshSharma This still gives the compiler error?

Answer (score -1):

you can add `any` to define the type of `out`

it will be something like that

```
var githubStream = this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users')

githubStream.subscribe((out: any) => {
  pipe(map(data => data.login))
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var githubStream = this.http.get<any>('https://api.github.com/users');

githubStream.subscribe(out => {
    pipe(map(data => data.login))
});
```

> Updated

```
 protected getUsers<T>(url: string):  Observable<T> {
return this.http.get<any>(url)
.pipe(map(data => {
  return data.body 
}));
```

}

```
this.getUsers.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.login)
    }
```

Comment: Doing this still produces the compiler error. See here: https://imgur.com/a/6zMfwmg

Comment: Would you mind to share your result data object ? which is coming from API?